# Deep learning CNN: low accuracy

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a convolutional neural network for binary time series classification. The training accuracy on both models is very different. If on the first it grows, then on the second it is always about 40%. There were also strong "jumps". Change filters=32/64/128 and epochs didn't give the best results(kernel_size = 8).

```
self.model = keras.Sequential([            
            Conv1D(64, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(self.frame_length, self.N_Feature)),
            BatchNormalization(),
            MaxPooling1D(),    
            
            Conv1D(128, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, activation='relu'),
            BatchNormalization(),
            MaxPooling1D(),    
            
            Conv1D(256, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, activation='relu'),
            BatchNormalization(),
            MaxPooling1D(),    
            
            Dropout(self.dropout_rate),
            Flatten(),
            Dense(self.N_classes, activation='sigmoid')
        ])        
        self.model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics='Accuracy')
```

[some learning outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2wQz.png)

Comment: It's hard to say much without more information on you're dataset. However, it seems you are massively overfitting on the training data. Maybe try some regularization methods such as dropout and L2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking a very wild guess (since your question is missing a lot of information), that your "self.N_classes" variable is "2"?

BinaryCrossentropy (your loss) needs it to be "1" though. So instead of labels being "[0, 1]" and "[1, 0]" they should be "0" and "1". If you change your labels, your loss should be calculated meaningfully and your training should work.

Comment: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape (1,)`
I'll try to find out what's wrong

Comment: Did you change Labels and self.N_classes? The Dense Layer should have output_shape=1

Comment: For a long time I tried to find what was wrong. These lines are in conflict:
1. `loader1.load_trainings_data(files_train, y_train)`
2. `self.trainings_data, self.trainings_label = self.load_data(files, label)`
3. `for j in range(N_Blocks):
tmp_label_vec[j] = label[i] # dim [N Blocks, N Classes]`

Comment: I think I can't find out from these lines what is wrong. If you can't figure it out yourself, create a new question and please include the full error message (if you are using notebooks press "+ Traceback" on the error message). Also it is really helpful if you replace variables like "N_Blocks" with the actual number.

Comment: Fixed this error. The training of the neural network has become relatively higher. But it "jumps" 0.9805 to 0.4505